# C# Web API project - sharing controllers through a library

Tags: asp.net

I have several projects with Web API REST interfaces.

Some of these interfaces are common across projects (like user management, etc.).

Is there a way to make a library that has controllers in it that I can include in various projects?

This doesn't seem to exist in VS' templates, but is it possible or do controllers require a lot of other things in place to compile?

Comment: What you need is not common controller but common service having common logic which you will call from your different projects.

Comment: Each of the project presents a web API; for example all of them have identical code for /users. The logic is already shared but I want to share the web part as well which is the controller

Comment: During runtime when route is resolved to find controller based on the url items it looks for controller in current assembly of  mvc project. This will fail if controller does not exist in the mvc project. You can override this behavior by writing your own controller factory to handle this specific use case. So it won't be an easy solution.

Comment: ok, so controllers that are not part of the main assembly will not be found?

Comment: Yes... they won't be found with the default controller factory. The best thing would be to have controllers in the web projects with action methods with max 2-5 lines of code which will call the the common service from the main assembly.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the answer takes just one line:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection Services)
    {
        Services.AddMvc()
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(SessionController).Assembly);
    }
```

You can add external controllers during the startup.
I am now checking if it is possible to add **all** controllers from an assembly at once.